# Is there a method like .every() for arrays with empty values?

Tags: javascript, foreach, iteration

My iteration has been working fine and dandy until know. I've encountered myself with an empty array and the .every() method doesn't work with that kind of values.

Here's the validation:

```
if(oJSonElementByIndex[sColumnName].every(x => typeof x == 'number'))
```

¿Any other options? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I think the one line of code is quite self-explaining in terms of *what* he wants to achieve...

Comment: @Robert not really... the question as a whole requires clarification

Comment: Every value of an empty array verifies any predicate you want. If that's not to your taste, you might want to test whether the array is empty beforehand, i.e. `if(array.length > 0 && array.every(predicate))`

Comment: "I've encountered myself with an empty array and the .every() method doesn't work with that kind of values".

If you have an object like this one: "key": [], the every() method won't suffice.

Comment: I would guess that it's not an empty yrray you are getting, but a null instead. And then the every() dies. What you should do is do a null check before you call .every()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there is no element in the array, every element in the array fullfills the condition. Therefore it returns true. To achieve the opposite:

```
arr.length && arr.every(/*...*/)
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `arr.length` rather than the more explicit `arr.length > 0` or the more concise `arr` ?

Comment: @aaron `arr` won't work. And i dont think that `> 0` makes it more readable.

Comment: @Aaron correct me if i'm wrong, but i think using the empty array doesn't work because of type coercion when using boolean logic operators: `[] && ...` will get coerced to `true && ...`

Comment: @worc I was pretty sure the empty array was coerced as boolean to false, but it turns out I'm wrong. I must have been thinking about python.

Answer (score 1):

So the comment about "every" predicate being fulfilled on an empty array, and the comment about using `array.length` and not just the array led me to putting together this snippet to illustrate.

The things to note here are the truthiness of an empty array, the falsiness of an empty array's length--zero, and the somewhat unintuitive logic idea that if you have *no* predicates then *all none of them* passed the condition:

```js
const empty = []
const typeofNumber = (x) => ( typeof x === 'number' )

console.log(`an empty array will return ${empty.every(typeofNumber)} on an every, since "every" predicate fulfilled the condition`)

if(empty.length && empty.every(typeofNumber)) {
  console.log('empty array length and every are truthy')
} else {
  console.log('empty array length and every are falsey')
}

if(empty && empty.every(typeofNumber)) {
  console.log('empty array and every are truthy')
} else {
  console.log('empty array and every are falsey')
}
```